# Printing pointers itself in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, printf, implicit-conversion

I am new to programming in C and I am trying to understand the concept of pointers. However, the result of some print statements are quite confusing and I was not able to find suitable answers online.

So, I was running the following `main` function in C:

```
int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // a points to the address of a[0]
    int *p = a; // p points to the same address as a
    int **pp = &p; // points to p

    int *p2[] = { a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4 }; // points a
    int **pp2 = p2; // points to the same address as p2

    printf("  a: %p,         *a: %p\n", a, *a);
    printf("  p: %p,         *p: %p\n", p, *p); 
    printf(" pp: %p,        *pp: %p,        **pp: %p\n",        pp,  *pp,  **pp);
    printf(" p2: %p,        *p2: %p,        **p2: %p\n",        p2,  *p2,  **p2);
    printf("pp2: %p,       *pp2: %p,       **pp2: %p\n",       pp2, *pp2, **pp2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

With `gcc main.c -o main` and `./main`  I got the following output:

```
  a: 0061FF04,         *a: 00000001
  p: 0061FF04,         *p: 00000001
 pp: 0061FEEC,        *pp: 0061FF04,        **pp: 00000001
 p2: 0061FEF0,        *p2: 0061FF04,        **p2: 00000001
pp2: 0061FEF0,       *pp2: 0061FF04,       **pp2: 00000001
```

which indicates that both `a` and `p` point to `a[0]` and `pp` to `p`, which is expected behavior. It also makes sense that `p2` and `pp2` point to the same address as `a`, but I cannot think of a reason, why printing out `a` and `p` as well as `p2` and `pp2` results in the same address (`0061FF04` and `0061FEF0`, respectively). Any help is appreciated

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/11082165) and [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/11082165)

Comment: Your code is generating lots of warnings when I try to compile it. `*a` is an `int`, but you're printing it with `%p`, which is for pointers. You have similar type problems in other printf statements.

Comment: _"a points to the address of a[0]"_ isn't quite right. `a` is an array. Arrays _are not_ pointers. It's just that they can be converted into a pointer to their first element. Same goes for `p2`.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You start out saying "`a` and `p` point to `a[0]`". So why are you surprised that printing them prints the same address?

Comment: Here's your program using the correct conversion specifiers and types in `printf`: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/r4E6jz4a9)

Comment: @user1132252 1) `a points to the address of a[0]` --> No.  `a` is an array not a pointer.  2) `p points to the same address as a` --> `p` is a pointer, `a` is an array.  Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.  `p points to the address of a[0]` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters all your calls to `printf` have undefined behavior because you use an invalid conversion specifier `p` with objects of the type `int`. To output objects of the type `int` you need to use conversion specifier `d` or `i`.

Arrays used in expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first element.

From the C Standard (**6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&`
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression
> with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the
> array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has `register`
> storage class, the behavior is undefined.

For example in this declaration

```
int *p = a;
```

the array `a` used as an initializing expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. You may equivalently rewrite the declaration the following way

```
int *p = &a[0];
```

Dereferencing the pointer `p` as in `*p` that is the same as `*a` or `p[0]` or `a[0]`: you will get the first element of the array `a`.

So you should write

```
printf("  a: %p,         *a: %d\n", ( void * )a, *a);
printf("  p: %p,         *p: %d\n", ( void * )p, *p);
```

In this declaration

```
int *p2[] = {a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4};
```

you define an array of pointers to elements of the array `a`.

So for example the array designator `p2` used in expressions is converted to a pointer to its first element.

So the pointer `pp2` declared as

```
int **pp2 = p2;
```

also receives the address of the first element of the array `p2`. That is the value of `pp2` is equal to the value of `p2` after implicit conversion of the array designator `p2` to a pointer to its first element.

On the other hand, expressions `*pp2` and `*p2`, that are the same as `pp2[0]` and `p2[0]`, yield the first element of the array `p2`. And expressions `**pp2` and `**p2`, that are the same as `pp2[0][0]` and `p2[0][0]` (or `( *pp2 )[0]`, `(*p2 )[0]` or `*pp2[0]`, `*p2[0]`), yield the first element of the array `a` because the first element of the array `p2` contains the address of the first element of the array `a`.

So you should write

```
printf(" p2: %p,        *p2: %p,        **p2: %d\n",        ( void * )p2,  ( void * )*p2,  **p2);
printf("pp2: %p,       *pp2: %p,       **pp2: %d\n",       ( void * )pp2, ( void * )*pp2, **pp2);
```

Though values of the expressions `pp2` and `p2` are equal (they both have the value of the address of the first element of the array `p2`) the values of `pp` and `pp2` are different because the pointer `pp` points to the pointer `p`. However the values of expressions `*pp2` and `*pp` are equal because the both point to the first element of the array `a`.

Comment: You need to quote from a more recent standard — C11 says: _Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof operator`, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue._. Note the addition of `_Alignof`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I provided the quote from ISO/IEC 9899:2017✿✿
2x (E). In ISO/IEC 9899:2023 (E) there is written "3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or typeof operators, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type “array of type” is converted
to an expression with type “pointer to type” that points to the initial element of the array object and
is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined." As you see _Alignof is absent by unknown for me reason.

Comment: Curious.  `_Alignof` was listed in C11.  I’ll have to poke around to see what (draft) C23 says.

Answer (score 1):

1. arrays in **C** decay to pointer referencing the first element of the array - same as `&array[0]` and it has the type of pointer to type of array elements.

- `&array` is referencing the same memory location as `array` but it has a different type (pointer to an array).

2. `p` is holding the reference of the first element of `a`. So printing `a` (as it decays to the reference of its first element) the  and `p` will print the same address.
3. `pp` is holding the reference of `p`. `*pp` will reference the first element of `a`
4. `p2` is an array of pointers holding references of array `a` elements (because of the decay from point 1)
5. `pp2` holds reference of the first element of the array `p2` (decay again). So printing `p2` and `pp2` will give you the same address.